# Creating a drop-down list in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm changing an old Excel spreadsheet and have got a user-request to add a drop-down list to a date selection field.

Data Validation is already turned on for the cell in question with a "<=TODAY()" clause (the sheet contains information on production efficiency, no idea going forward since data is not there).

The user requests a drop-down listing the past seven days. I can make a list and enumerate it in VBA, but I am having difficulties coming up with a way to apply a drop-down list to a cell without using Validation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some ways you can try:

1. Add a **datepicker** to the cell (and keep the formula validation you put)
   a. See some standard way on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4za48s1h)
   b. or with an addin on [this blog](http://www.yogeshguptaonline.com/2010/01/excel-macros-excel-date-picker.html)
2. **Change dynamicaly** your validation to a dropdown list when the Workbook is opened or the worksheet activated with an [event procedure](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) and add another event procedure `OnChange` to check if the value entered is *before today*.

Comment: Just a note: if the workbook did not previously contain macros, adding macros will change the user experience quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Why not replace the existing data validation rule with a list rule?  Just create a new sheet and enter in A1:A7

```
=TODAY()
=A1-1
...
=A1-6
```

Then set your data validation rule to "List" and set the Source to A1:A7 on the new sheet. Then hide the sheet just to keep it out of the way. This should preserve the old validation requirement.